# Issue with JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I've written a code which displays search results which are images in JTable..

The main problem is that even after adding JScrollbar, the scorll bar does not appear even when its needed...

Here is a snapshot of my code..

`this.queryName = qname;`

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1)); //.. UPPER FOR QUERY AND LOWER FOR RESULT

    this.ijtable = new ImageJTable(result, Setting.getColumnCount());
    ijtable.setVisible(true);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(ijtable);

    JLabel query = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageResize.resize(queryName, Setting.getQueryWidth(), Setting.getQueryWidth())));
    query.setVisible(true);

    frame.add(query);
    frame.add(ijtable);
    frame.add(pane);

    frame.setSize(Setting.getFrameWidth(), Setting.getFrameHeight());
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because you are adding both `ijtable` and `pane`. Only add `pane` because that control has `ijtable` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.add(ijtable);
```

Try removing this line. By adding the table to the frame, you're removing it from the scroll pane.